Wazuh installation error
I'm using Hyper-V with Ubuntu version 20.04. Before run the command curl -sO https://packages.wazuh.com/4.9/wazuh-install.sh && sudo bash ./wazuh-install.sh -a, I run the following command:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install curl.

Here is the log of what I got:
07/12/2024 21:36:47 INFO: Starting Wazuh installation assistant. Wazuh version: 4.9.2

07/12/2024 21:36:47 INFO: Verbose logging redirected to /var/log/wazuh-install.log

07/12/2024 21:36:51 INFO: --- Dependencies ----

07/12/2024 21:36:51 INFO: Installing gawk.

07/12/2024 21:36:57 INFO: Verifying that your system meets the recommended minimum hardware requirements.

07/12/2024 21:36:57 INFO: Wazuh web interface port will be 443.

07/12/2024 21:37:03 INFO: --- Dependencies ----

07/12/2024 21:37:03 INFO: Installing apt-transport-https.

07/12/2024 21:37:06 INFO: Installing debhelper.

07/12/2024 21:37:33 INFO: Wazuh repository added.

07/12/2024 21:37:33 INFO: --- Configuration files ---

07/12/2024 21:37:33 INFO: Generating configuration files.

07/12/2024 21:37:34 INFO: Generating the root certificate.

07/12/2024 21:37:34 INFO: Generating Admin certificates.

07/12/2024 21:37:35 INFO: Generating Wazuh indexer certificates.

07/12/2024 21:37:35 INFO: Generating Filebeat certificates.

07/12/2024 21:37:35 INFO: Generating Wazuh dashboard certificates.

07/12/2024 21:37:37 INFO: Created wazuh-install-files.tar. It contains the Wazuh cluster key, certificates, and passwords necessary for installation.

07/12/2024 21:37:37 INFO: --- Wazuh indexer ---

07/12/2024 21:37:37 INFO: Starting Wazuh indexer installation.

07/12/2024 21:38:27 INFO: Wazuh indexer installation finished.

07/12/2024 21:38:27 INFO: Wazuh indexer post-install configuration finished.

07/12/2024 21:38:27 INFO: Starting service wazuh-indexer.

07/12/2024 21:38:41 INFO: wazuh-indexer service started.

07/12/2024 21:38:41 INFO: Initializing Wazuh indexer cluster security settings.

07/12/2024 21:38:45 INFO: Wazuh indexer cluster security configuration initialized.

07/12/2024 21:38:45 INFO: Wazuh indexer cluster initialized.

07/12/2024 21:38:45 INFO: --- Wazuh server ---

07/12/2024 21:38:45 INFO: Starting the Wazuh manager installation.

07/12/2024 21:39:23 ERROR: Wazuh installation failed.

07/12/2024 21:39:23 INFO: --- Removing existing Wazuh installation ---

07/12/2024 21:39:23 INFO: Removing Wazuh manager.

07/12/2024 21:39:26 WARNING: The Wazuh manager package could not be removed.

07/12/2024 21:39:26 INFO: Removing Wazuh indexer.

07/12/2024 21:39:27 WARNING: The Wazuh indexer package could not be removed.

07/12/2024 21:39:27 INFO: --- Dependencies ----

07/12/2024 21:39:27 INFO: Removing gawk.

07/12/2024 21:39:27 ERROR: Cannot remove dependency: gawk.

From the wazuh-install.log, I find some log as follow:

Selecting pr dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wazuh-manager_4.9.2-1_am cannot copy extracted data for './var/ossec/tmp/vd_1.0.0_vd_4.8.0.tar.xz' to '/var/ossec/tmp/vd_1.0.0_vd_4.8.0.tar.xz.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error new wazuh-manager package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit st E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

So I'm running out space of my virtual machine? But I already assign 8000 MB RAM, 4 virtual processors, virtual hard disk of 50 GB, which is not enough?

Disk full is going to be about your hard disk, not your RAM or CPU.
